# Can somebody give an active record example for pluginaweek - statemachine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, state-machine

Can somebody give a simple example on howto use [pluginaweek state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) for a ticket model with active record?
I do not understand the complex examples from the docs.

Example states:

- new -> accepted, declined, feedback
- accepted -> solved or feedback
- feedback -> accepted or solved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example ticket model (not tested)

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description
  attr_accessible :state_event
  validates :name, :presence => true

  state_machine :initial => :new do

    event :accept do 
      transition [:new, :feedback] => :accepted
    end

    event :decline do
      transition :new => :declined
    end

    event :feedback do
      transition [:new, :accepted] => :feedbacked
    end

    event :solve do
      transition [:accepted, :feedback] => :solved
    end
  end
end
```

Get all possible transitions in form

```
<%= f.collection_select :state_event, @ticket.state_transitions, :event, :human_to_name, :include_blank => @ticket.human_state_name %>
```

Get state of ticket: `<%= ticket.state %>`

Get all possible ticket transitions as links:

```
<% ticket.state_transitions.each do |transition| %>
    <%= link_to transition.event, ticket_path(ticket, ticket: {:state_event => transition.event}), :method => :put %>
<% end %>
```

List all possible transitions to filter in controller

```
<ul>
  <li class="<%= 'active' if params[:state].blank? %>"><%= link_to 'All', tickets_path %></li>
  <% Ticket.state_machine.states.each do |state| %>
    <li class="<%= 'active' if params[:state] == state.name.to_s  %>">
      <%= link_to state.name, tickets_path(:state => state.name) %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

class TicketsController extends ApplicationController
  ...
  def index
    @tickets = Ticket.where("state = ?", params[:state])
    ...
```