# Best practice for observing RESTful routing in Rails and coupling resource models and controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, rest, controller

Strict REST proponents might say that if you ever find yourself defining an action on a controller that isn't CRUD, then you should strongly consider creating a new resource and defining your action as a CRUD operation on the new resource.

An example might be operations that change state on a model - say Purchase. In this example, instead of defining a 'complete' action on PurchaseController you might create a CompletePurchasesController and use the create action to update the purchase's state to completed.

Assuming the above, you obviously don't persist PurchaseState directly to the database.

My question is when do you couple the Controllers to Models? When do you define a PurchaseState model (which isn't persisted) and when do you simply work directly with Purchase.

Is it a question of complexity and the number of loosely associated models you are interacting with in the Controller actions?

Answer (score 0):

'Complete' is a state transition event on (an existing) purchase. I find it counter-intuitive to conceptualize this action as a create on a virtual resource rather than an update action on a controller coupled to the Purchase model, in fact PurchaseController itself.

I would define individual update-like actions for such state transitions. I think this way you can leverage rails structure in the most economical way, including model-initialisation, view dispatching, routing, access control. Let's assume you use inherited_resources, cancan by simply adding

```
# routes.rb
resource :purchase do 
  put :complete, :on => :member
end

# purchase_controller.rb
def complete
  @purchase.complete!
end

# cancan ability (entry already there for basic crud)
can :manage, Purchase, :user_id => user.id
```

you are already done implementing the entire UI (view/model logic aside).
How utterly cool is that in rails.

If your typical usecase is that purchase is only updated by state transitions, especially all having the same access rights and redirect views, then I would even use the update action of PurchaseController with state_event attributes. See

[Can somebody give an active record example for pluginaweek - statemachine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559702/can-somebody-give-an-active-record-example-for-pluginaweek-statemachine)

Strict REST-ists, bite me! :)

Answer (score 0):

For updating the purchase state, you probably only need a PurchasesController update action, which you would define in your routes file as a 'put' or 'patch' method.

If all that happens on update is changing the state field on your purchase object, you can probably just do that right in the update action.

If there's some business logic around some of the state transitions, but ultimately you're only changing that purchase object, you probably want to put that in your Purchase model.

If other tables are also updated, or you're also doing things like queuing up an email to your user congratulating them on their new purchase, I think that's when you might add a separate PurchaseComplete or PurchaseAbort models / service objects. These seem to come into play most naturally when the logic for the action is more complex, and/or you have changes to more than one model, or are doing something else.